# Is it allowed to ask for participation on a photography survey?

Tags: discussion

I'm writing my master thesis and need participants for my survey. It is a survey about photography and how the photograph tries to detect sharp photos on the camera display.
Is it ok or not to ask on photo.stackexchange.com for participants?

Answer (score 3):

You can not ask it on the main site, but you would be welcome to join us in chat (if you have sufficient rep) and ask people there.  It isn't the same audience as the main site, but still has probably 15 to 20 regular people that visit the room.

Comment: AFAIK, you only need a rep of 20 for chat, so he's good. :)

Comment: Right, I was thinking 50 for some reason, but that's comment everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not. Generally, this is a site for questions with answers and you're question would not match up with this from [the help](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.
>
> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of course welcome in our real time web chat.)